# How do you write text doc info (names and numbers) into multiple arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, ifstream

I've been racking my brain trying to get this information from a text doc into a few different arrays. The number before each name in the txt doc is the identification number, I want to put all these into a single double array. Then put every name into a single string array. Then finally put the numbers after each name into a double 2d array with 50 rows (one for each name) and 7 columns (for the seven scores/numbers for each client). I'm not asking for anyone to do my homework for me, I just need some info on how to get started.

```
using namespace std;
int main() { ifstream file("client_info.txt");
    string txtArray[450];

    for (int i = 0; i < 450; ++i)
    {
        file >> txtArray[i];
    }
```

I thought maybe I'd put all of the text into a string array then split that array into several other arrays, but realized it would be difficult to use strings, since I need the numbers to be doubles for later when I'm finding the average of the clients scores.
Here is the txt doc:

93 SMITH 739.15 634.36 257.02 639.32 376.75 360.56 666.96 81 JOHNSON 888.08 975.86 672.78 176.35 114.58 511.24 502.56 50 WILLIAMS 222.27 171.83 232.83 609.79 726.69 444.89 520.63 32 JONES 343.13 687.73 931.93 72.36 183.93 486.3 90.09 68 BROWN 623.39 968.13 67.59 528.93 703.95 329.02 875.95 24 DAVIS 97.48 296.61 568.49 990.18 448.36 567.52 179.42 21 MILLER 147.68 38.87 64.78 463.19 172.39 914.68 827.42 90 WILSON 687.7 595.19 930.52 77.27 877.45 774.44 599.83 29 MOORE 739.33 402 825.29 859.63 937.14 405.2 89.22 12 TAYLOR 976.11 531.4 731.45 815.16 518.26 858.86 832.34 31 ANDERSON 133.12 355.22 517.53 926.54 552.05 932.52 745.75 89 THOMAS 217.72 266.14 622.99 541.35 618.49 268.9 243.63 87 JACKSON 352.81 772.31 109.43 139.14 430.43 625.92 207.79 46 WHITE 650.79 367.65 915.68 848.85 912.44 603.15 704.01 75 HARRIS 708.38 70.53 34.45 409.82 288.28 735.06 140.9 85 MARTIN 701.73 643.16 766.3 198.92 805.86 802.39 239.76 67 THOMPSON 993.9 274.75 72.87 928.41 208.81 260.42 5.56 52 GARCIA 871.48 646.48 914.77 98.61 724.86 680.7 363.15 60 MARTINEZ 293.38 448.24 985.08 135.2 277.77 705.58 567.81 69 ROBINSON 914.18 688.95 112.81 270.18 950.27 607.49 915.75 76 CLARK 956.12 110.6 820.53 140.97 906.2 529.52 75.24 82 RODRIGUEZ 224.88 324.32 672.74 502.27 768.99 116.42 880.86 39 LEWIS 805.89 274.54 211.14 82.04 804.41 259.69 408.08 48 LEE 80.06 381.7 975.29 448.33 578.49 548.19 818.85 26 WALKER 657.74 0.74 741.06 533.84 887.36 38.35 619.17 55 HALL 266.9 46.42 825.89 986.01 146.96 349.07 386.64 100 ALLEN 293.22 423.57 150.53 519.25 16.96 65.54 688.44 11 YOUNG 870.69 192.46 82.19 92.46 971.38 156.49 16.48 57 HERNANDEZ 145.33 123.45 860.78 521.86 739.9 138.88 169.33 96 KING 411.31 340.93 447.04 14.26 744.1 425.83 57.87 4 WRIGHT 503.48 488.13 603.12 198.14 425.51 216.28 49.75 64 LOPEZ 296.99 744.89 270.49 138.19 897.06 374.89 831.66 62 HILL 910.95 676.68 442.98 961.03 567.6 739.49 225.26 37 SCOTT 970.31 468.48 788.85 903.66 897.93 124.04 983.01 34 GREEN 260.42 714.42 496.13 492.39 170.17 999.36 890.8 51 ADAMS 212.36 115.84 308.57 741.29 780.3 193.71 423.82 40 BAKER 316.91 671.36 398.53 190.99 424.34 457.68 584.16 47 GONZALEZ 947.9 348.88 299.11 71.82 727.49 480.59 891.51 3 NELSON 160.13 962.1 903.76 107.34 127.07 844.07 575.1 36 CARTER 981.92 250.09 5.39 866.43 182.93 135.12 224.91 78 MITCHELL 805.83 181.19 549.25 815.72 776.2 887.33 144.86 28 PEREZ 144.04 616.81 637.07 342.41 818.58 901.72 104.02 8 ROBERTS 880.38 62.34 591.34 721.18 184.64 378.08 439.94 99 TURNER 21.83 227.82 378.42 680.24 336.24 703.13 52.36 2 PHILLIPS 664.1 879.16 811.4 842.3 463.96 446.52 919.31 17 CAMPBELL 392.91 26.12 591.74 766.1 30.91 108.24 863.81 33 PARKER 359.87 606.99 61.67 188.85 474.87 159.02 907.38 30 EVANS 770.78 70.1 724.89 490.02 667.93 116.4 938.55 70 EDWARDS 507.59 698.53 15.5 251.9 340.84 246.6 233.04 44 COLLINS 803.53 580.38 966.57 941.38 249.58 562.3 725.05

Comment: So instead of one array of strings, declare all the arrays you need. And then read into them inside your loop. I'm not sure where you are having a problem.

Answer (score 0):

To make a multideminsional array use

```
type arrayName [x][y];
```

The first number is row, second is column. You can use arrayName[0][x] to set the names you mentioned, assuming you use each row for a single name and whatever properties belong to that name. Hope this helps :)

Comment: I actually have no idea how to read files and get data from them, but cplusplus.com uses "getline" to do similar things

Answer (score 0):

With error checking omitted:

```
const int NUM_PERSONS = 50;
const int SCORES_PER_PERSON = 7;

double scores[NUM_PERSONS][SCORES_PER_PERSON];
int ids[NUM_PERSONS];
std::string names[NUM_PERSONS];

for(int i = 0; i < NUM_PERSONS; ++i) {
    file >> ids[i] >> names[i];
    for(int j = 0; j < SCORES_PER_PERSON; ++j) {
        file >> scores[i][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: I meant to put number of columns as 6 because each person has six doubles numbers (their expenses/or scores) after there name, and one double number before their name which is their ID. I tried changing the value of SCORES_PER_PERSON to 6 but trying to compile it made the code break. I really appreciate the help, thanks.

Comment: @Alex Are you sure? I count seven doubles and then the ID (which looks like an integer to me) in your sample input.

Comment: You are one hundred percent correct I've been reading it with a terrible txt. doc reader. Thank you, again.